# Why would an incorrect password attempt take a lot longer to process than a correct one?

Tags: linux, performance, passwords

The most prominent place I've noticed this is when SSH-ing at work, but I feel like I've observed this behaviour elsewhere too.

When I try to log into Linux servers from my Windows desktop at work, I've noticed that if I mis-type my password, it takes a good 5 seconds or so before I get "Access Denied" back. Then when I type my password correctly, the login (along with welcome messages etc) is virtually instant.

Is there any logical reason for this, or would it be down to some odd configuration that's specific to the machines here at work?

Comment: There is a good discussion/answer of this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712339/why-should-checking-a-wrong-password-take-longer-than-checking-the-right-one, including specifically reducing the Linux fail delay [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2953794/1037948) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3181141/1037948)

Comment: the same will happen when you log into Windows with an incorrect password, but I notice the time varies from time to time, in a wide range from a few seconds to about 1-2 minutes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's probably an artificial timeout built-in to make it harder for a brute force attack to succeed.

You will see this on many login prompts that involve secure authentication...

Comment: Ah, hadn't thought of that. That makes perfect sense, and would explain why I feel like I've seen the same delay elsewhere.

Comment: aka tarpitting.  Thanks,  Michael Kjörling (http://superuser.com/questions/916187/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-the-computer-to-respond-with-invalid-password-wh/916189?noredirect=1#comment1234282_916189)

Answer (score 10):

This is some intended delay to prevent brute force attacks. A longer delay also prevents the attacker being able to guess the difference between username is wrong and password is wrong (hashing and checking the password takes noticeable longer time than checking the username).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this **deliberate delay** is to prevent attacks like the **"Linearization attack"** *(there are other attacks and reasons as well)*.

> To illustrate the attack, **consider a program (without this
>   deliberate delay), which checks an entered serial to see whether it
>   matches the correct serial, which in this case happens to be
>   "*xyba*"**. For efficiency, the programmer decided to check one
>   character at a time and to exit as soon as an incorrect character is
>   found, before beginning the lengths are also checked.
>
> **The correct serial length will take longer to process than an incorrect serial length. Even better (for attacker), a serial number
>   that has the first character correct will take longer than any that
>   has an incorrect first character. The successive steps in waiting time
>   is because each time there's one more loop, comparison to go through
>   on correct input.**
>
> - So, attacker can select a *four-character string* and that the string beginning with *x* takes the most time. *(by guess work)*
> - Attacker can then fix character as *x* and vary the second character,    in which case they will find that *y* takes the longest.
> - Attacker can then fix the first two characters as *xy* and vary the third character, in which case they will find that *b* takes the
>     longest.
> - Attacker can then fix the first three character as *xyb* and vary the fourth character,in which case they will find that *a* takes the
>     longest.
>
> Hence, the attackers can recover the serial one character at a time.

**[Linearization.java.](https://github.com/user501254/TE_IT_6_SWS/blob/master/Linearization/Linearization.java)**

**[Linearization.docx, sample output](https://github.com/user501254/TE_IT_6_SWS/blob/master/Linearization/Linearization.docx)**

> The serial number is four characters long ans each character has 128
>   possible values. **Then there are 128<sup>4</sup> = 2<sup>28</sup> =
>   268,435,456 possible serials**. If attacker must randomly guess
>   complete serial numbers, she would guess the serial number in about
>   **2<sup>27</sup> = 134,217,728 tries, which is an enormous amount of work**. On the other hand, by using the linearization attack above, an
>   average of only 128/2 = 64 guesses are required for each letter, for a
>   total **expected work of about 4 * 64 = 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 guesses,**
>   which is a trivial amount of work.

*Much of the written martial is adapted from [this](https://bookstreet.in/questions/what-is-malware-explain-salami-and-linearization-attacks-10-marks-925) (taken from Mark Stamp's "Information Security: Principles and Practice"). Also the calculations above do not take into account the amount of guesswork needed to to figure out the correct serial length.*