# Disable Windows 8 incorrect password delay

Tags: windows-8, passwords

Whenever I type the incorrect password in to my Windows 8 machine login it takes longer and longer before I can attempt to reenter the password again.

[I believe this is a security feature and by design](https://superuser.com/questions/355674/why-does-the-login-check-take-longer-if-the-password-is-wrong)

I want to disable this - I have looked under windows policies and settings but cannot find anything. Does anyone know where I can disable this security feature in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Group Policy called [Account lockout duration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994569(v=ws.10).aspx)

It's the same for Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Vista

It will accept a value range or 0 - 99,999 so if you set it to 0 it will no longer give you a delay.

Policy is stored at the following location:

> \Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy

---

This can also be done through command line:

```
C:\Users\foo>net accounts
Force user logoff how long after time expires?:       0
Minimum password age (days):                          1
Maximum password age (days):                          30
Minimum password length:                              8
Length of password history maintained:                10
Lockout threshold:                                    5
Lockout duration (minutes):                           30
Lockout observation window (minutes):                 30
Computer role:                                        WORKSTATION
The command completed successfully.
```

Then we just run `net accounts /lockoutthreshold:0` and `net accounts /lockoutduration:0` we get the below:

```
C:\Users\foo>net accounts
Force user logoff how long after time expires?:       0
Minimum password age (days):                          1
Maximum password age (days):                          30
Minimum password length:                              8
Length of password history maintained:                10
Lockout threshold:                                    0
Lockout duration (minutes):                           Never
Lockout observation window (minutes):                 30
Computer role:                                        WORKSTATION
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: running from the command line doesn't work for me, even when I open it as administrator

Answer (score 0):

This other article probably answers the question:

[How to reduce the time Windows takes to report a password is wrong?](https://superuser.com/questions/635934/how-to-reduce-the-time-windows-takes-to-report-a-password-is-wrong)

Maybe Windows is trying to reach the domain controller and has to wait for the timeout when it cannot. It seems like there is no better explanation at the moment.

It surely is not the Account Lockout duration because this happens after entering the password wrong only once, even though Lockout is disabled in my Windows 8 machine.

This last comment in the above link is useful:

> Windows 8 seems to have increased the lockout delay to the point where
>   it's literally quicker to forcefully shutdown the computer and reboot
>   after entering a wrong password, rather than wait for the timeout to
>   pass. – Wallacoloo