# Why successful login in Windows 10 is faster than an unsuccessful login

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, login

On Windows 10 it seems that after entering the login credentials, the time to login successfully is way shorter than the time for unsuccessful attempt. Where does Windows search for account, when we successfully login probably it utilizes a cached detail and does not consult the server? Any further insight, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would an incorrect password attempt take a lot longer to process than a correct one?](https://superuser.com/questions/351410/why-would-an-incorrect-password-attempt-take-a-lot-longer-to-process-than-a-corr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the login check take longer if the password is wrong?](https://superuser.com/questions/355674/why-does-the-login-check-take-longer-if-the-password-is-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=14513) on Microsoft devblogs, it is for technical and security purposes.

The credentials' hashes are stored on your local machine for fast authentication. If your credentials do not match the one you have on your machine, it tries to contact the domain controller to get the hash again.

Also, a longer verification time makes it more difficult to perform brute-force attack on the Windows computer directly. The attacker need to extract the hash to brute-force it on an external machine or deal with the longer waiting time.

If you want to learn more about how winlogon works, I suggest that you search for this registry key : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`