# Why does a failed linux login take so long?

Tags: linux, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would an incorrect password attempt take a lot longer to process than a correct one?](https://superuser.com/questions/351410/why-would-an-incorrect-password-attempt-take-a-lot-longer-to-process-than-a-corr)

When you get the correct login credentials, you are logged in immediately. When you get your password wrong, there's a second delay before you're notified and able to try again.

Is this a prevention against cracking, or is there something else going on behind the scenes?

Comment: I've noticed a flaw on a couple of Linux systems which permitted me to login as 'bin' without requiring a password!

Comment: @Frank - what distro? I find this very surprising.

Comment: distro=distributions.. yeah, for the longest time, there's been a security flaw which very few people know that allow a hacker to obtain the password for root!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is a prevention against cracking. It is a forced delay, usually about 2 or 3 seconds delay before a new login prompt is issued. This helps prevent automated attacks by making the iteration too long to be practical.

On linux, it can be configured in the `/etc/login.defs` file.

```
# Delay in seconds before being allowed another attempt after a login failure.
FAIL_DELAY              3
```

Comment: On my machine, that config file says that FAIL_DELAY is obsoleted by pam and should be handled in the /etc/pam.d/login file (pam_faildelay.so)

Answer (score 16):

The main reason is, like you said, to stop automated attacks. It just slows down a potential "bad guy" if he can only try ten passwords a minute instead of a hundred.

You'll also notice that the shell completely restarts after 3 or 4 failed attempts. I *think* this is to detach or kill any attached processes which could be malicious.

Answer (score 7):

I guess it's a form of "[Tarpitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_%28networking%29)" where the server delays incoming connections for as long as possible