# What resource do I need to upgrade for Windows to reject my password faster?

Tags: windows-10, passwords

I'm having a problem where Windows 10 takes around 10-20 minutes when I enter my password incorrectly. This has been happening for over a year, on a few different versions of 10. Since I can't see Task Manager during this time, I don't know what resource is being constrained. My password isn't very complicated, it's in the style of *Hunter2*. Is there something I need to upgrade for Windows to reject my password faster?

Specs:

- 8gb ram
- Intel i5 8350U (4C/8T)
- NVMe SSD

Windows build: 20H2.

Comment: The worst I see (Windows 10 and 11pre-release) is one minute.  Try a different user profile.

Comment: You do know the amount of time Windows takes between rejects increases as a security measure right? It's called [tarpitting](https://superuser.com/questions/916187/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-the-computer-to-respond-with-invalid-password-wh) and I don't believe the delay can be disabled.  You might want to go with a slightly easier password to type.

Comment: There is nothing you can upgrade. The timeout is by design to prevent brute-force attacks.